# Remove/Edit "Switch Back..." message in facebook like button

Tags: css, iframe, facebook-like

If you are logged in as one of your Facebook business pages, the Facebook "like" button will show you Facebook avatar and then the message "Switch back to [your facebook name] to use this social plugin."

My problem is that I've placed the like button in a column with a limited width so there is no room for this message. [Here is a link to it](http://passportal.com.au).

I've seen it on other sites too, like [this one](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-mobile-touching).

Comment: Maybe make your HTML wider to accommodate or build you own like widget that you can fit in the special narrow width?